# How can i create a image slider in my app

Tags: android

I am developing an app. In which i need to integrate image slider. Please give me all code for xml. I am new developer so please give.

Here is my `MainActivity` code.

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fragment_page.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**swipe_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    static final int NUM_ITEMS = 6;
    ImageFragmentPagerAdapter imageFragmentPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    public static final String[] IMAGE_NAME = {"eagle", "horse", "bonobo", "wolf", "owl", "bear",};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);
        imageFragmentPagerAdapter = new ImageFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(imageFragmentPagerAdapter);
    }

    public static class ImageFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public ImageFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            SwipeFragment fragment = new SwipeFragment();
            return SwipeFragment.newInstance(position);
        }
    }

    public static class SwipeFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View swipeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_fragment, container, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) swipeView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            int position = bundle.getInt("position");
            String imageFileName = IMAGE_NAME[position];
            int imgResId = getResources().getIdentifier(imageFileName, "drawable", "com.swipeimageslider");
            imageView.setImageResource(imgResId);
            return swipeView;
        }

        static SwipeFragment newInstance(int position) {
            SwipeFragment swipeFragment = new SwipeFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("position", position);
            swipeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return swipeFragment;
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.swipeimageslider" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look library https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider for sliding images with great animations